# Update Code To work now that tab has been moved to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet

I have a code which reviews data held in a table & if a new line is added to master table "Mini Master" it adds it onto the list in a different tab "Critical Path".

```
Sub test()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim toWs As Worksheet
Dim rngDB As Range, rngT As Range
Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer

Set Ws = Sheets("MINI MASTER")
Set toWs = Sheets("CRITICAL PATH")

vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
With toWs
    Set rngDB = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngDB, vDB(i, 1)) Then
        Else
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 4, 1 To n)
            For j = 1 To 4
                vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    Set rngT = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    If n Then
        rngT.Resize(n, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

This worked really well but now I would like to hold the "Critical Path" in its own workbook, rather than a tab of the same workbook.

I tried to update the code to reference the new file locations but its not quite working.

```
 Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
    Set Ws = Workbook.Open("U:\Buying\BUYING\Buying Spreadsheets\MiniMaster.xlsm")
    Dim toWs As Workbook, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Set toWs = Workbook.Open("U:\Buying\BUYING\Buying Spreadsheets\CriticalPath.xlsm")
    
    Dim rngDB As Range, rngT As Range
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
    
    Set wsSource = Ws.Sheets("MINI MASTER")
    Set wsTarget = toWs.Sheets("CRITICAL PATH")

    vDB = wsSource.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    With wsTarget
        Set rngDB = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngDB, vDB(i, 1)) Then
            Else
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 4, 1 To n)
                For j = 1 To 4
                    vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
        Set rngT = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        If n Then
            rngT.Resize(n, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Not sure what I have done wrong here & would love some help resolving the issue.

Comment: What does "not quite working" mean? Error messages or just not doing what you want?

Comment: In which workbook is the code you show written in? Is it `MiniMaster.xlsm`? If so you cannot open it again and need to change `Set Ws = Workbook.Open("U:\Buying\BUYING\Buying Spreadsheets\MiniMaster.xlsm")` into `Set Ws = ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: @SJR - I get an error Run Time Error 424 - Object required.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - I want it to run in the '("U:\Buying\BUYING\Buying Spreadsheets\CriticalPath.xlsm")'. I have tried changing the 'toWs = thisworkbook' but get the same error mentioned above.

Comment: *"same error mentioned above"* In which line of code is this error? • `Set toWs = ThisWorkbook` is defenitely correct if the code is in `MiniMaster.xlsm` as you cannot open this file if it is already open (which it has to be in order to run its code).

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: `Workbook.Open` >> `Workbooks.Open` but as noted do not use this if the workbooks are already open.